# Formula for the total Hamming weight of the sequence of 1, 2, ..., n

Tags: math, binary, hammingweight

This problem is fairly straightforward if `log2(n)` is a whole number as we can use a simply use:

```
n * log2(n)/2
```

however it miscounts when `log2(n)` isn't a whole number. My intuition is there should be a formula similar to this that works for all n but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: I  guess it is `for i from 1 to log2(n):`

Comment: And in this simple case, the result seems to be `n * log2(n)/2`